# Push Android Library to Github

Tags: android, git, github

I've made a 2-module project where one module is completely denoted to a library that I've made and I'm accessing that library from the other module(which contains the MainActivity.java) of the project. Now I want to push only my library to the GitHub so that anyone can use it for their need. I know how to push the entire project to GitHub but How can I extract the library ( module ) from the project and push only that. **Thanks in Advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, your root project is already versioned under git. If so then to version your library module as a separate git repo and also use it within other git repo projects, then you need to use [git-submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). The module will be pushed as a separate Android Project. Once that is done, you'll add the library to your app project by using `git-submodule` and configuring the `settings.gradle` to include the library module for compiling. And finally, add a dependency in your app `build.gradle` file to include the library in the app compilation.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? My library module name is "imagegrad" . Now How can I push it to GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple, maybe I misunderstand your need

```
git add <modulename.extension>
git commit -m "added single module"
git push origin master
```